# Getting min and max values of ordered categorical data in Pandas with describe?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, describe

I have a mixed Pandas dataframe of numerical and categorical data. I ordered the categorical data and I'm able to get the min and max values with the min() and max() functions, but can't get them with the describe function. Is there a way to use the describe function with ordered categorical data and get the min and max values?

Code:

```
data_clean.indiv1 = 
data_clean.indiv1.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'], ordered=True))
print('min', data_clean.indiv1.min())
print('max', data_clean.indiv1.max())
print('describe')
print(data_clean.indiv1.describe())
```

Output:

```
min F
max A

# With describe()
count     64
unique     2
top        A
freq      52
Name: indiv1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), the `describe` function with ordered categorical data cannot get the min and max.

> Using describe() on categorical data will produce similar output to a
>   Series or DataFrame of type string.

Comment: Yes, but it is kind of weird because I can get the min and max values with their respective functions, but the describe just ignores them (or in the case of mixed datatypes, fills it with NaN).